# Windows 10 IoT Core GPU utilization

Tags: windows-10, iot

How come there is no data visible for the GPU Utilization in the Windows IoT Core Device Portal?

Comment: What board are you using Windows 10 IoT Core on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the driver is not yet available to utilize the GPU. You will notice this when doing using video and complex UI's.